# Highcharts JS Uncaught TypeError: x[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I'm building a bar chart, retrieving the options from ajax response. But when i pass the object to the highcharts constructor im getting the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: x[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a constructor
```

My ajax response is like this(validated with JsonLint):

```
{
    "chart": {
        "type": "column"
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "Resumo diario de Movimentos"
    },
    "subtitle": {
        "text": "Selecione os Fornecedores em questão"
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "categories": [
            "Indiferenciado", "Papel / Cartão", "Madeira", "Vidro", "Metais", "Ramagem", "Pneus", "Plástico Não Reciclável", "Embalão", "REEE", "Lâmpadas", "Pilhas", "Compostagem", "Diversos Incineração", "Diversos Aterro", "Outros", "Diversos", "Embalão/Vidro", "Roupas e Brinquedos", "Cemitério", "Papel", "Cartão", "Papel Porta a Porta", "Orgânico", "RX", "Orgânico Porta a Porta", "Embalão Porta a Porta", "Vidro Porta a Porta", "Plástico Filme", "Esferovite", "Mad. Shopping", "Forum Madeira", "Mad. Carlton", "Capa 2", "Oleos Alimentares Usados", "Papel Saco Azul", "Estilha", "Baterias", "Paletes"
        ],
        "crosshair": true
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "min": 0,
        "title": {
            "text": "Peso (Kg)"
        }
    },
    "tooltip": {

        "shared": true,
        "useHTML": true
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "column": {
            "pointPadding": 0.2,
            "borderWidth": 0
        }
    },
    "series": [{
            "name": "Tokyo",
            "data": [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 55],
            "visible": false
        }, {
            "name": "Tokyo",
            "data": [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 55],
            "visible": false
        }

    ]
}
```

Now when im trying to initiate the highcharts with the incoming data

```
 <script>
     $(function(){
         $.post("/ajax/getResumo/diario")
                 .done(function(dataInc) {
                     $("#chartContainer").highcharts(dataInc);
                 });
     });

    </script>
```

Im getting the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: x[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a constructor
```

But if i Copy+Paste the Response from my ajax directly into the Highcharts constructor it's working fine.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#chartContainer").highcharts(JSON.parse(dataInc));
```

had to parse, the incoming response was coming as a strng